# How do I Unit Test the Output of a View in MonoRail?

Tags: unit-testing, castle-monorail

I've been trying to write some initial NUnit unit tests for MonoRail, having got some basics working already. However, while I've managed to check whether a Flash["message"] value has been set by a controller action, the BaseControllerTest class doesn't seem to store the output for a view at all, so whether I call RenderView or the action itself, nothing gets added to the Response.OutputContent data.
I've also tried calling InPlaceRenderView to try to get it to write to a StringWriter, and the StringWriter also seems to get nothing back - the StringBuilder that returns is also empty.
I'm creating a new controller instance, then calling 
PrepareController(controller,"","home","index");

So far it just seems like the BaseControllerTest is causing any output to get abandoned. Am I missing something? Should this work? I'm not 100% sure, because while I'm also running these unit tests in MonoDevelop on Linux, although MonoRails is working OK there.

Comment: You do not have a view engine set within the test context. Depending on the ViewEngine you actually use, you'd need to initialize it and add it to the test context. 

Anyway, I would reconsider running integration tests that goes all the way down to the views. these kind of tests tend to be very brittle, with low-to-negative ROI. Make sure you leave all logic outside of the views.

Comment: I'm trying to keep logic out of views, and have created a ViewComponent which I'll also want to test. I'm not expecting to unit test all views, but I am wanting to put together a sample test to demonstrate how it's done for if I'm having problems getting a particular page right.

Comment: I'll leave off the trying to unit test a view for now - I have a kind of solution in being able to test pages with Selenium, although only via the browser as MonoDevelop and Selenium RC don't seem to be playing well together either. I'll still need to have a different way of testing a ViewComponent - this should be able to be unit tested, from what I've read, but I'm still short of any sample code to show how to set up the properties for it, etc

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't got an ideal method for testing Views, this is possibly less important when ViewComponents can be tested adequately. To test views within the site itself, I can use Selenium. While in theory that can be made part of an NUnit test suite, that didn't run successfully under MonoDevelop in my tests (failing to start the connection to Selenium RC consistently, despite the RC interactive session working fine). However, the Selenium tests can be run as a set from Firefox, which is not too bad - unit testing with NUnit, then Integration/System testing scripting using a Selenium suite, and that setup will work in a Linux/MonoDevelop setup.

As for testing the underlying elements, you can check for redirections and check the flash value set or the like, so that's all fine, and for testing ViewComponents the part-mocked rendering does return the rendered output in an accessible form, so they've proved much easier to test in NUnit (with a base test class of BaseViewComponentTest) as follows:

```
[Test]
public void TestMenuComponentRendersOK()
{
   var mc = new MenuComponent();
   PrepareViewComponent(mc);
   var dict = new System.Collections.Specialized.ListDictionary();
   dict.Add("data",getSampleMenuData());
   dict.Add("Name","testmenu");
   // other additional parameters
   mc.RenderComponent(mc,dict);
   Assert.IsTrue(this.Output.Contains(""),"List items should have been added");
}
```